# Use MergeSort to process user input

Tags: java

I want to sort an input(from command line arguments) set of numbers, been stucking here for 3days without finding the error of my codes...really desperate...

Will anyone please give me a hint?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSorter 
{

    public MergeSorter(int[] anArray)
    {
        a = anArray;
    }
    public void sort()
    {
          if (a.length <= 1) return;
          int[] first = new int[a.length / 2];
          int[] second = new int[a.length - first.length];

          System.arraycopy(a, 0, first, 0, first.length);
          System.arraycopy(a, first.length, second, 0, second.length);

          MergeSorter firstSorter = new MergeSorter(first);
          MergeSorter secondSorter = new MergeSorter(second);
          firstSorter.sort();
          secondSorter.sort();
          merge(first, second);
    }
    private void merge(int[] first, int[] second)
    {
        int iFirst = 0;
        int iSecond = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while (iFirst < first.length && iSecond < second.length) 
        {
            if (first[iFirst] < second[iSecond])
            {
                a[j] = first[iFirst];
                iFirst++;
            }
            else
            {
                a[j] = second[iSecond];
                iSecond++;
            }
            j++;
        }
          System.arraycopy(first, iFirst, a, j, first.length - iFirst);
          System.arraycopy(second, iSecond, a, j, second.length - iSecond);
       }
    private int[] a;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] a = new int[args.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) 
        {
            a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        MergeSorter sorter = new MergeSorter(a);
        sorter.sort();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: If this isn't an exercise on Mergesort, you can simply use `Arrays.sort(array);`, which is a mergesort.

Comment: man!!! u really pull me out of the misery...god bless u

Comment: Umm.. I just ran you code and it sort just like it's supposed to?!

Comment: It works without any problems. What is the error?

Comment: to Anthales...not really it just sort the no. partly and i dont know why...still wondering what's wrong with my codes

Comment: Are you sure it's not an input problem? Your sorter is correct.

Comment: OMG seems like somehow i didnt realise i've solved the problem...but yesterday i got the wrong result again n again...anyway thanks guys

Comment: now i just wondering what happened overnight ^_^ i guess as a beginner at some point u get completely lost

Comment: special thanks to Martijn Courteaux. u showed me a much easier method

Comment: is it an easier way to reverse the results without using for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this isn't an exercise on Mergesort, you can simply use `Arrays.sort(array);`, which is a mergesort.

For sorting in descend order, you can specify your own comparator.

```
Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<Integer>()
{
    public int compare(Integer i1, Integer i2)
    {
        return -i1.compareTo(i2);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Harvey: When someone helped you out by posting an answer, you can click the tick next to the answer to accept that answer. This is the StackOverflow marks questions as Solved. Welcome by the way to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Running a test code:

```
Random r = new Random();

int testCase = 0;
out: while (true) {
    System.out.println("Test case " + testCase++);

    //Create array of random length (from 0 to 999) and random content
    int[] a = new int[r.nextInt(1000)];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        a[i] = r.nextInt();

    //Try to sort (in ascending order)
    MergeSorter sorter = new MergeSorter(a);
    sorter.sort();

    //Test if sorted
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
        if (a[i+1] < a[i]) //not ascending
        {
            System.out.println("Array is not sorted!");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
            break out;
        }
    }
}
```

Doesn't find any case in which your sorter doesn't sort (I ran it to about 1.000.000 test cases)!

Answer (score 1):

It works normally.
Try to write:

```
java MergeSorter 7 3 5 3 5
```

it gives:

```
[3,3,5,5,7]
```

But if you write:

```
java MergeSorter 73535
```

it gives same as input, because of one int argument:

```
[73535]
```

Comment: I know that is single number. In my opinion author might made mistake as in this example.